# Find the maximum difference between the limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

Let $ C=\int_{a}^{b} (7x-x^2-10) dx $  where $a<b$

Determine the maximum value $(b-a)$ can assume if  $C=0$

This question has troubled me for some time, and I would like some help to solve this problem.
The correct answer is $(b-a)≈5.2$

I plotted the graph of the quadratic polynomial and found that $a=0.5$ and
$b=5$ leads to $C=0$
[Here is the picture of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFnVE.png)

But this means that $(b-a)=4.5$  which is the wrong answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE @Gabriel. Please tell us what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: I plotted the graph of the quadratic polynomial and tried to choose a and b so that the "positive" area balances the "negative" area. The problem is that there are a lot of values of a and b that satisfies this condition. I dont know which combination will yield the maximum difference between b and a

Comment: Please add this attempt in the body of the question then.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i added my attempt in the body of  the question.

Comment: You will get a bigger interval if you make it symmetric about the axis of symmetry, which is $x=3.5$

Comment: Why would that give me a bigger interval?

Comment: What you wrote doesn't make sense. The claim is that the maximum value of $b-a$ is about $5.2$. You just found a case where $b-a=4.5$, which is less than $5.2$, as expected.

Comment: the negative part of the integrand will be less negative the closer you stay to the axis of symmetry, this gives the answer ~ 5.19615

Answer (score 4):

We have that

\begin{align*}
\int_a^b(7x-x^2-10)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\biggl[\frac{7}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{3}x^3-10x\biggr]_a^b \\
&=\frac{7}{2}(b^2-a^2)-\frac{1}{3}(b^3-a^3)-10(b-a) \\
&=(b-a)\left(\frac{7}{2}(b+a)-\frac{1}{3}(a^2+ab+b^2)-10\right) \\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Make now the change of variables

$$\begin{cases}
u=b-a,\\
v=b+a,
\end{cases}$$

so that

\begin{align*}
0
&=\frac{7}{2}(b+a)-\frac{1}{3}(a^2+ab+b^2)-10 \\
&=\frac{7}{2}v-\frac{1}{3}\left(v^2-\frac{1}{4}(v-u)(v+u)\right)-10 \\
&=\frac{7}{2}v-\frac{1}{3}\left(v^2-\frac{1}{4}(v^2-u^2)\right)-10 \\
&=-\frac{1}{12}u^2-\frac{1}{4}v^2+\frac{7}{2}v-10.
\end{align*}

Rearranging we get that

$$u=\sqrt{-3v^2+42v-120}=\sqrt{27-3(v-7)^2}$$

(note that $u=b-a>0$ as we can assume $b>a$, so we take the positive root). From this it is clear that the biggest value of $u=b-a$ is $\sqrt{27}=3\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Writing $b-a$ in terms of $b+a$ here is quite clever; nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Another way to do it*

Let $b=c+a$ which gives for the integral
$$I=-\frac c 6\left(2c^2+3 (2 a-7)c+6 (a-5) (a-2)\right)$$  Just a quadratic equation in $c$ whose roots are
$$c_\pm=\frac{1}{4} \left((21-6a)\pm \sqrt{3(-4 a^2+28 a-13)}\right)$$ Considering $c_+$ and differentiating
$$(c_+)'=\frac{1}{4} \left(-6+\frac{\sqrt{3} (28-8 a)}{2 \sqrt{-4 a^2+28 a-13}}\right)$$ Again a quadratic equation
$$(c_+)'=0 \quad \implies \quad a=\frac{7-3 \sqrt{3}}{2} $$
and, for this value of $a$,
$$c_+=3 \sqrt{3}$$